# How to generate schema for multiple choice filter?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-filter, drf-yasg

In our API we have an endpoint to list locations. We allow filtering on location type, and we allow multiple values for this filter. For example:

```
GET /location/?type=hotel&type=airport
```

For filtering we are using `django-filter`. However, `drf-yasg` doesn't seem to correctly generate the schema for this parameter.

The view class can be boiled down to this:

```py
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from .models import Location
from .serializers import LocationListSerializer
from .filters import LocationFilterSet
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class LocationListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Location.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LocationListSerializer
    filter_backends = (
        DjangoFilterBackend,
    )
    filter_class = LocationFilterSet
```

and the filter class looks like this:

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from .models import Location

class LocationFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    type = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=Location.TYPE_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = (
            'type',
        )
```

This view works as intended - the following test passes:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from .models import Location

class TestLocationView(TestCase):
    def test_filter_by_multiple_types(self):
        Location.objects.create(type='airport')
        Location.objects.create(type='hotel')
        Location.objects.create(type='home')
        response = self.client.get('/location/?type=hotel&type=airport')
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data), 2)
```

I'd expect the generated yaml for this parameter to look like this:

```
parameters:
- name: type
  in: query
  description: ''
  required: false
  schema:
      type: array
      items:
          type: string
  explode: true
```

but instead, it looks like this:

```
- name: type
  in: query
  description: ''
  required: false
  type: string
```

Is this a limitation of `drf-yasg`?

It's not possible to use `swagger_auto_schema`'s `query_serializer` since it doesn't allow overriding the schemas generated by the filter backends.

This seems to happen because `django_filters.rest_framework.backends.DjangoFilterBackend.get_coreschema_field` only outputs two field types, number and strings. I went ahead and overrode that method, however, it then throws errors in `drf_yasg.inspectors.query.CoreAPICompatInspector.coreapi_field_to_parameter`, doesn't accept the array type.

Comment: I ended up using a CharFilter with a method argument, splitting the string by comma, etc. There's a issue for this: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/118